# How to use gdb debug compiled code from R package within rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I have some code running fine at R console, but crashes the R session in Rstudio. I wonder if it is possible to attach gdb to the r session in rstudio for trouble shooting?

Comment: Check this out: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207601737-How-to-debug-a-fatal-error-

Comment: Thanks! I was able to backtrace with gdb following the instruction of the link above.

Comment: here is the stacks https://gist.github.com/mikejiang/f1218d22b0a34968958e89f861235dc3  But unable step in after selecting the frame,